# Parsing XML With Java Trying To Get Attribute On Namespace Childnode

Tags: java, xml, parsing, nodes

Here is my XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Pport xmlns="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/v12" xmlns:ns3="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2" ts="2016-07-26T20:51:30.9941484+01:00" version="12.0">
   <uR updateOrigin="TD">
    <TS rid="201607264120116" ssd="2016-07-26" uid="W44875">
     <ns3:Location tpl="LEEE" wtp="21:00:30">
      <ns3:pass et="20:57" src="TD"/>
      <ns3:plat cisPlatsup="true" platsrc="A" platsup="true">1</ns3:plat>
     </ns3:Location>
    <ns3:Location tpl="LEESPRJ" wtp="21:02:30">
     <ns3:pass et="20:59" src="Darwin"/>
    </ns3:Location>
    <ns3:Location tpl="GRVPDCE" wtp="21:15:30">
     <ns3:pass et="21:12" src="Darwin"/>
    </ns3:Location>
    <ns3:Location tpl="GRVPCSD" wta="21:21">
     <ns3:arr et="21:17" src="Darwin"/>
     <ns3:pass et="20:59" src="Darwin"/>
    </ns3:Location>
   </TS>
  </uR>
 </Pport>
```

Here is part of my code:

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    Document doc = builder.parse(is);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root Element : " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(
        "http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2", "Location");
    int totalBooks = nList.getLength();
    System.out.println(totalBooks);

    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(i);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            System.out.println(eElement.getAttribute("tpl"));

            String tpl = eElement.getAttribute("tpl");
            String pta = eElement.getAttribute("pta");
            String ptd = eElement.getAttribute("ptd");
            String wta = eElement.getAttribute("wta");
            String wtd = eElement.getAttribute("wtd");

            //New Code 2
            System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagNameNS(
                "http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2","arr").getAttribute("et"));

            String query = "insert into darwinall (tpl,timestamp,pta,ptd,wta,wtd)"
            + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            try {
                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connectOut.connect().prepareStatement(query);
                preparedStmt.setString(1, tpl);
                preparedStmt.setInt(2, 123456);
                preparedStmt.setString(3, pta);
                preparedStmt.setString(4, ptd);
                preparedStmt.setString(5, wta);
                preparedStmt.setString(6, wtd);

                preparedStmt.execute();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can successfully get attributes tpl,pta,ptd,wta and wtd. However I cannot get the attribute for **"et"** within the node namespace **ns3:arr**. I do not want to get the "et" within **ns3:pass**. The answer I am after is 21.17. I am cycling through the ns3:Location nodes. The piece of code thats at fault is under //New Code 2. I get an error saying...The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type NodeList. Any help appreciated

Comment: `getElementsByTagNameNS` returns a `NodeList `. You probably want to call `item()` on it to get a specific item you can call `getAttribute()` on.

Comment: Hi GriffeyDog. Do you mean like this...System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagNameNS("http........","arr").item(0).getAttribute("et"));...............it still shows as an error

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. [`Element.getElementsByTagNameNS()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagNameNS-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) returns a [`NodeList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html), not an `Element`. So you have to iterate over it the same way you are iterating over your `Location` nodes:

```
String tpl = eElement.getAttribute("tpl");
String pta = eElement.getAttribute("pta");
String ptd = eElement.getAttribute("ptd");
String wta = eElement.getAttribute("wta");
String wtd = eElement.getAttribute("wtd");
String et  = "";

NodeList nArrList = eElement.getElementsByTagNameNS(
         "http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2", "arr");

for (int k = 0; k < nArrList.getLength(); k++) {
    Node innerNode = nArrList.item(k);
    if (innerNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element innerElt = (Element) innerNode;
        et = innerElt.getAttribute("et");
    }
}

/* Do database stuff... */
```